# Switch alt-tab to ctrl-tab on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook-pro

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook Pro, and I am trying to switch the "Switch Applications" shortcut from <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Changing the shortcut via the Keyboard application does not seem to have any effect, even after restarting. The application says that the "Switch Applications" shortcut is now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I can still only switch windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I have previously switched my control and command keys by modifying `~/.Xmodmap` to the following, and suspect that there may be an unwanted interaction.

```
remove control = Control_L
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
keysym Control_L = Super_L
keysym Super_L = Control_L
keysym Super_R = Control_L
add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
```

Many thanks; I am having a wonderful time with Ubuntu so far.

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy (and i did it) with unity Tweak tool>Switcher or CompizConfig settings manager that you can install one (or both) of them easily from Ubuntu Software Center or with Terminal.

Comment: CompizConfig settings manager makes Compiz crash when I change a shortcut and try to use it. I do not want to use Unity Tweat tool as I already have MyUnity and Ubuntu Tweak (which also makes Compiz crash when I try to change a shortcut) and all these programs seem to make my desktop more buggy.

Comment: i have all tweak programs on Ubuntu 13.04 working without any issues ! (your problem may be caused after a package installation. Yes ? i  think so because i had a problem like this on Ubuntu 12.04 before .

Comment: I don't get any other problems with the tweak programs besides changing shortcuts